# How to re-size the image to specific dimensions(without compromising the quality of uploaded image) uploaded by user in optimum way using PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, image-resizing, php-gd

I'm using **PHP, jQuery, AJAX, HTML,** etc. for my website. I'm a newbie to PHP.

I have used one jQuery image slider in my WebApp. For this image slider user uploads images. Further, these uploaded images are displayed into this image slider. This functionality is working fine for me.

This image slider has fixed width and height of **940 px * 370 px**. I want to allow user upload images whose dimensions should be greater than or equal to **940 px * 370 px**.

Suppose, user uploads image with dimensions **2215 px * 875 px** then this image should be re-sized to dimensions **940 px * 370 px** before it get uploaded to the server(i.e. before saving the image to the server). Only after re-sizing the uploaded image to **940 px* 370 px** it should get saved to the server.

During this process of re-sizing the quality of image must not be get affected. The re-sized image should look like the original image uploaded by user. It should not get shrinked or stretched in any sense.

How should I achieve this functionality in an optimum way by using PHP GD and Image Functions?

For your reference I'm putting below the code I tried for file upload functionality:

**HTML Code :**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code :**

```
    <?php
      $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
      $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $extension = end($temp);

      $image_dimesnions = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
      $image_width = $image_dimesnions[0];
      $image_height = $image_dimesnions[1];

  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5242880)
    && ($image_width < 940 || $image_height < 370)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can use imageMagick to convert image.Check url http://www.imagemagick.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on server using imagemagick commandline tool or using [PHP GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

More information link of ImageMagick -

1. [About ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php)
2. [Command Line Options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)
3. [Resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize)

Information link of PHP GD Library -

1. [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)
2. [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)
3. [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
4. [imagecreatefromgif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Use Below Command To convert image -

```
$w = 940;
$h = 370;
$temp_path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$dest_path = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -resize \"$w"."X".$h.">\"  $dest_path  $temp_path");
```

Use below code for PHP GD-

```
            <?php
$uploadPath = "/var/www/stack/26201855/upload/";
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$imageType = "";
if(strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'jpeg') || strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'jpg') || strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'pjpeg')){
$imageType = "jpeg";
}else if(strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'png') || strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'x-png')){
$imageType = "png";
}else if(strpos($_FILES["file"]["type"],'gif')){
$imageType = "gif";
}

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
if (file_exists($uploadPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$images = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$new_images = $uploadPath.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
copy($images,$new_images);
$width=940;
$size=GetimageSize($images);
$height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
if($imageType === 'jpeg'){
$images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
}else if($imageType === 'png'){
$images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images);
}else if($imageType === 'gif'){
$images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
}
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
if($imageType === 'jpeg'){
imagejpeg($images_fin,$new_images);
}else if($imageType === 'png'){
imagepng($images_fin,$new_images);
}else if($imageType === 'gif'){
imagegif($images_fin,$new_images);
}


ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
echo "Stored in: " . $uploadPath. $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
}
} else {
echo "Invalid file";
} 
?>
```

**Note:** You have to decide yourself which is  convenient way to resize image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this sounds quite a tricky way to me. Can't be there any other easier and simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Installing the third party library, using command line tools are the somewhat tedious kind of jobs. I want to avoid them.

Comment: If I use the second approach(PHP GD library) do I need to import any file, install any extension or create some object, etc. Or writing the code you given in answer would be enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62481/discussion-between-rajesh-ujade-and-user2839497).

Comment: I have updated the answer. Problem is in path.Please try to learn how to debug. `copy(["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);`
instead of `copy($_FILES,"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);`. Now you can use the answer code as it is in your file.